# Assign value to specific cell in PySpark dataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I want to change a value in a specific cell of my `Spark DataFrame` using `PySpark`.

Trivial example - I create a mock `Spark DataFrame`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     (1, 1.87, 'new_york'), 
     (4, 2.76, 'la'), 
     (6, 3.3, 'boston'), 
     (8, 4.1, 'detroit'), 
     (2, 5.70, 'miami'), 
     (3, 6.320, 'atlanta'), 
     (1, 6.1, 'houston')
    ],
    ('variable_1', "variable_2", "variable_3")
)
```

Runnning `display(df)` I get this table:

```
variable_1   variable_2   variable_3
    1           1.87    new_york
    4           2.76    la
    6           3.3     boston
    8           4.1     detroit
    2           5.7     miami
    3           6.32    atlanta
    1           6.1     houston
```

Let´s say for example, I would like to assign a new value for the cell in the 4th row and 3rd column, i.e. changing `detroit` for `new_orleans`. I know assignments as `df.iloc[4, 3] = 'new_orleans'` or `df.loc[4, 'detroit'] = 'new_orleans'` are not valid in `Spark`.

A valid answer to my question using `when` would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
targetDf = df.withColumn("variable_3", \
              when(((df["variable_1"] == 8) & (df["variable_2"] == 4.1)) , 'new_orleans').otherwise(df["variable_3"]))
```

My question is: could this be done in a more practical way in `PySpark` without the necessity of entering all the values and column names of the row where I want to change just 1 single cell (maybe achieving the same without using the `when` function)?

Thanks in advance for your help and @useruser9806664 for his feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Consider using Pandas DataFrame

It is true that Spark DataFrames are immutable and therefore, they are not designed to be modified. Spark Dataframes are distributed data collections optimized for processing large amount of data and if you want to make any changes you would have to create a new one with the modifications you want.

Nevertheless, there will be times when you might need to modify a specific cell for a specific row. For these situations you could modify the column using the *when* function (like you did in your example) with the values of the cells in the same row as the specific cell that you want to modify. Or you could **consider converting your Spark Dataframe into a Pandas DataFrame** (which are **muttable**) and, **after assigning the new value to the cell in question, transform it back into a Spark DataFrame**. Here is how you could do it:

```
# Copy the schema of your Spark dataframe 
schema = df.schema

# Create Pandas Dataframe using your Spark DataFrame
pandas_df = df.toPandas()

# Assign the new value to the specific cell (you could use .at or .loc)
pandas_df.at[3, 'variable_3'] = 'new_orleans'

# Update your dataframe with the new value using the Pandas DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df,schema=schema)

# Delete the auxiliary pandas dataframe to free memory for other uses
del pandas_df
```

Keep in mind that Pandas DataFrames are not distributed and processing in the Pandas DataFrame will be slower for a large amount of data.

Answer (score 15):

Spark `DataFrames` are *immutable*, *don't provide random access* and, strictly speaking, *unordered*. As a result:

- You cannot assign anything (because immutable property).
- You cannot access specific row (because no random access).
- Row "indcies" are not well defined (because unordered).

What you can do, is creating a new dataframe with new column, replacing existing, using some conditional expression, which is already covered by the answers you found.

Also, `monotonically_increasing_id` doesn't add indices (row numbers). It adds monotonically increasing numbers, not necessarily consecutive ones or starting from any particular value (in case of empty partitions).

Comment: Thank you @user9806664 for your answer. I was aware of immutability of Spark reading "Scala/Spark: Immutable Dataframes and Memory" titled SO post. Nevertheless, is it possible to create a new dataframe doing that substitution you mention in another form (not entering all values of each column in the row where we want to modify 1 cell)? If so, could you provide an example? I will edit my question to be more clear thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a row number using the underlying RDD:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Function to update dataframe row with a rownumber
def create_rownum(ziprow):
    row, index=ziprow
    row=row.asDict()
    row['rownum']= index
    return(Row(**row))

# First create a rownumber then add to dataframe
df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(create_rownum).toDF().show()
```

Now you can filter the DataFrame to obtain the row number you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I used sql expresions:

```
expr = """CASE WHEN variable1==8 AND variable==4.1 THEN 'new_orleans' ELSE variable3 END AS variable4"""

df = df.selectExpr(*,expr)
```

Comment: Explanation of code would help other users to understand the answer.